# Fundamental group of a circle with rational lines

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the union of

- the unit circle
- the $y$-axis
- all lines through the origin with rational slopes

equipped with the subspace topology. Is there a simple characterization of $\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: I don't know if there's any kind of reasonable description of it, but it seems unlikely. I believe it is uncountable.

Comment: @MattSamuel it is countable but has countably (infinitely) many generator, actually any path- two line from origin and a arc in between them would be a generator

Comment: @Anubhav I believe you can also have loops (obviously not rectifiable) spanning infinitely many spokes.

Comment: No you cannot have in that sense, it will break the rule of compactness then

Comment: It can still be compact. Take the lines with slope $1/n$ and 0, along with the circle, and you get a compact set.

Comment: @MattSamuel yes, that is a compact set no doubt...but problem rising while getting a loop which winded around infinitely many times, there you can use some limit point argument to get some contradiction

Comment: @MattSamuel Such a 'loop' should be represented by an infinite product of elementary loops (those which are given by the obvious generating loops), which doesn't make sense in a group.

Comment: @Dan no, it wouldn't be an infinite product. It would be an element not in the subgroup generated by the elementary loops. Look up the Hawaiian earring.

Comment: @MattSamuel The Hawaiian earring has a fundamental group which is uncountable. That group is not generated just by the elementary loops, it has generators which are described by loops whose image includes infinitely many of the loops, but which still has 'finite length' (and so is well defined). That is, $\pi_1(H.Earring)$ surjects onto the infinite product $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$. The space in this question surjects onto the infinite sum $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Dan I'm not in the mood to argue much more, but I just wanted to note that loops need not have finite length. For example the Peano space filling curve can be turned into a loop with infinite length.

Comment: @DanRust What is the difference between $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$ and $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @M.Vinay Both have elements which are infinite sequences of elements from $\mathbb{Z}$ but the sum has the property that we only allow infinite strings which are non-zero on finitely many coordinates. In particular the elements $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ is not in the infinite sum but is in the infinite product.

Comment: @DanRust Okay, thanks. I don't really see the rationale, if any, behind this convention [though I see that it is a common one]. Derek Robinson denotes the infinite product using $\operatorname{Cr}$ (cartesian/unrestricted product) and the infinite sum using $\operatorname{Dr}$ (external direct product) instead of $\prod$ and $\oplus$.

Comment: It comes from the fact that the product and sum of abelian groups are the 'product' and 'coproduct' respectively in the category of abelian groups and then the definitions I gave above turn out to fall out of the definition in terms of the product and coproduct.

Comment: @DanRust Ah, that makes a lot of sense!